# Which Selector names in external css?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I first styled my images and headings right in my aspx but to make the code look neat i want to put all styles into an external style sheet.
But now whenever i take all the formats and copy it to my style sheet,that is correctly linked to my aspx page it doesnt work. Some has an id to it and others has a class to it. The noraml tags like `<h1> <p>` works well but those tags that are in a table wont work

Here is my code

```
<table>  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="Images/DoradoTop.jpg" alt="Dorado Image 1" class="DefaultImage"/>                            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my Css attempt to edit the image:

```
img.DefaultImage
{
   border: meduim solid #006699;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 550px;
   height: 380px;
}
```

my other attempt

```
table tr td img.DefaultImage
{
   border: meduim solid #006699;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 550px;
   height: 380px;
}
```

these dont work and i have no idea how to call them up in css

any help will do

Comment: The class names can not contain whitespaces.

Comment: iv taken away all spaces it still doesnt work

Comment: does `img { border: 2px solid red; }` work for you? if not, make sure the stylesheet is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`img.Default.Image`

This is correct. Using `img.Default Image` you are looking for tag `Image` inside tag `img` with class `Default`.

Comment: You have also `meduim` instead of `medium` in your border style.

Comment: Oh wow one spelling error and it made the whole thing not work,'

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx pages may be generating additional HTML code, especially if their is any code-behind that is dynamically loading content onto your page.  SharePoint does that, as an example. If you want to really "own" your selectors and ID's, download Google Chrome, open up developer tools and see what the HTML content looks like AFTER the DOM is ready.

Then copy the HTML table you see from their and compare it to the table you are showing everyone in your initial example above, and see if they look the same.

Developer Tools is great for debugging front-end web code.

You can do it!

Comment: Thanks alot Im very new to web developing and programming so sometimes i ask very silly questions but so i will learn